# p-column datafields alignment in mobile

Tags: html, css, angular, mobile, responsive

I am trying to align my datafields to the left in p-column when converted to mobile.

I have tried by varying width percentage for the column in style, but I couldn't figure it out. Here is my code.

```
 <p-dataTable>  

 <p-column [style]="{'width':'14%'}" field="manufacturer" header="Manufacturer" [sortable]="true"  [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"></p-column> 

 </p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: sorry, I din get you. If you were talking about the question readability I modified it. If not can you plz elaborate?

Comment: When I use the moderator tools, it will also add my moderation comments here -- which can be highly confusing sometimes. I was just trying to help you get an answer here by improving your question quality.

Comment: Alright thanks, can you please help me with the question?